# Using a SOCKS5/HTTPS proxy as a VPN adapter in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, proxy, vpn

I have a proxy server in `IP:PORT` format, and I am using Proxifier to launch the apps on my PC through the proxy.

The problem here is that I want to use the proxy server to reduce my ping time in the Valorant game, but as I launch the game through Proxifier it seems like the game is not connected to the proxy server and it has the ping I have through normal direct connection.

I have tried running Valorant using a VPN connection and it seems that the VPN connection changes the ping (not in a good way though!).

What I want is some kind of software or tunnel that connects to that IP:PORT and acts as a VPN adapter in Windows (like OpenVPN, PPTP, L2TP, etc.).

Comment: Can you explain me how did you run the game using proxifier. When I tried doing the same i was not even able to run the program and the log shows that the riotClient failed to establish the connection to the proxy server.

Comment: @VamsiReddy You should uncheck Proxifier's DNS Settings under "Profile > Name Resolution" , the proxy only works for the party and matchmaking functionalitites the game won't use it because the in game internet somehow uses a localhost process and tunnels it through localhost

Comment: Although the Anti-Cheat software might be the problem, because Fortnite's Anti-Cheat blocks Proxifier and shows the block message in its log.